QIcon.fromTheme does not load a jpg image
I am facing a problem with QIcon.fromTheme when loading a .jpg image. I use QIcon.fromTheme to switch icons in the app depending on the theme selected by the user. It works well with .svg icons (for toolbar buttons) but when I try to use this method with a .jpg image that I want to set as my background's mainwindow it's not working (background's image should also change when user switch theme). I have tried with different .jpg images and I get the same result: image is not displayed. There is no error message on the shell.
If I use the relative path to the .jpg image using QIcon instead it works (displaying the image, not in switching it).
I am using a QLabel with the method .setPixmap to hold the .jpg image. This is my code:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, 
    QMainWindow, 
    QToolBar,
    QStatusBar,
    QAction,
    QLabel
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QSettings
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from model.models import Base
import resources_rc  ## <-- compiled file from resources.qrc
import qtstylish
import sys
import os

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ICONS_WIDTH = 32
ICONS_HEIGHT = 32

try:
    from ctypes import windll

    myappid = "isDev.sistemaGestorUrimare.administrativo.version1.0" 
    windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass

if not os.path.isfile(root + "/model/database.db"):
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///model/database.db", echo=True)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

settings = QSettings("Urimare", "urimareApp")

if not settings.contains("theme"):
    settings.setValue("theme", "/resources/light")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sistema Gestor Urimare")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/logo/logo.png"))
        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(parent=self))

        if settings.value("theme") == "/resources/light":
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light())
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.dark())

        # setThemeName must contains the relative path to the diretory where index.theme is
        QIcon.setThemeName(settings.value("theme"))

        self.image = QIcon.fromTheme("background")  ## <-- here is my problem
        self.image_pixmap = self.image.pixmap(QSize(700, 700))
        self.background = QLabel(parent=self)
        self.background.setPixmap(self.image_pixmap)
        self.background.setScaledContents(True)

        self.new_client = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("new_client"))
        self.new_client.setStatusTip("Registrar nuevo cliente")

        self.update_client = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("update_client"))
        self.update_client.setStatusTip("Actualizar cliente")

        self.new_company = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("new_company"))
        self.new_company.setStatusTip("Registrar nueva compañía")

        self.update_company = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("update_company"))
        self.update_company.setStatusTip("Actualizar compañía")

        self.new_product = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("new_product"))
        self.new_product.setStatusTip("Añadir nuevo producto")

        self.update_product = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("update_product"))
        self.update_product.setStatusTip("Actualizar producto")

        self.new_quotation = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("quotation"))
        self.new_quotation.setStatusTip("Crear nueva cotización")

        self.update_quotation = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("update_quotation"))
        self.update_quotation.setStatusTip("Actualizar cotización")

        self.dark_light_theme = QAction(parent=self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme("dark_light_theme"))
        self.dark_light_theme.setStatusTip("Cambiar tema de la aplicación")
        self.dark_light_theme.triggered.connect(self.switch_theme)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar(parent=self)
        self.toolbar.setMovable(False)
        self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(ICONS_WIDTH, ICONS_HEIGHT))
        self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.addActions(
            [
                self.new_client, 
                self.update_client,
                self.new_company,
                self.update_company,
                self.new_product,
                self.update_product,
                self.new_quotation,
                self.update_quotation,
                self.dark_light_theme
            ]
        )

        self.setCentralWidget(self.background)
        self.resize(self.image_pixmap.width(), self.image_pixmap.height())

    ### SLOTS ###

    def switch_theme(self):
        if settings.value("theme") == "/resources/light":
            settings.setValue("theme", "/resources/dark")
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.dark())
        else:
            settings.setValue("theme", "/resources/light")
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light())

        QIcon.setThemeName(settings.value("theme"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

and this is my resources.qrc:
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="icons">
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/new_client.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/update_client.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/new_company.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/update_company.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/quotation.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/update_quotation.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/dark_light_theme.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/new_product.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/update_product.svg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/background.jpg</file>
    <file>resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/cat.jpg</file>
    <file>resources/light/index.theme</file>

    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/new_client.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/update_client.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/new_company.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/update_company.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/quotation.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/update_quotation.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/dark_light_theme.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/new_product.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/update_product.svg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/background.jpg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/iconosSVGAmarillos/cat.jpg</file>
    <file>resources/dark/index.theme</file>
</qresource>

<qresource prefix="logo">
    <file alias="logo.png">resources/iconosApp/urimareIcono02.png</file>
</qresource>

Am I missing somethig? maybe QIcon.fromTheme does not support .jpg files? Thanks in advance!
This is a print of my MainWindow:


The freedesktop icon theme specification (also linked in the fromTheme() docs) seem to only support PNG, XPM and SVG formats. I would suggest using PNG against JPG anyway, both for optimization and quality reasons.

@musicamante Thanks! I will switch to png the background image.

as @musicamante pointed out the solution was to convert the .jpg image to a .png and it works! I can load it using QIcon.fromTheme. Thanks again!

The fromTheme() documentation hints that it's based on the freedesktop icon specification (also linked there). It's not really clear how it is actually supported and, most importantly, respected, but the specification actually explains this aspect:

Icon file

An icon file is an image that can be loaded and used as an icon. The supported image file formats are PNG, XPM and SVG. PNG is the recommended bitmap format, and SVG is for vectorized icons. XPM is supported due to backwards compability reasons, and it is not recommended that new themes use XPM files. Support for SVGs is optional.


This means that, for compatibility reasons, JPEG images are probably not supported (no matter if the QImageReader plugin supports them, as it's possible that Qt relies on the native icon theme loading when using fromTheme() on compatible platforms).
In any case, the JPEG format can be considered obsolete (but still valid) nowadays, both for performance and quality reasons, and the PNG format should be considered anyway for this purpose, since it generally provides better compression/quality/speed ratios in almost any case.
If possible, reconvert the sources of those jpgs to pngs, otherwise convert those jpgs to pngs directly, eventually checking the compression ratio: most of the times, you'll end up with the same looking image, but with a smaller size or, possibly, the same computation effort.
Also, remember that a bitmap representation (QImage/QPixmap) will still require the same amount of process memory, no matter the format of the source file: a fully white 500x500 image will occupy different sizes on disk whether it's stored as BMP, GIF, JPG or PNG, but will occupy the same size in memory once loaded as an actual image data.
